# show annihilator is subspace of dual space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $Y$ be a subspace of $X$, then define set of linear functions in $Y^{\perp} := \{l(y) = 0, \forall y \in Y\} $

Show that $Y^{\perp}$ is a subspace of the dual space $X'$.

Basically, we need to show $Y^{\perp}$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication of linear functions in $Y^{\perp}$.

Correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: It's more correct to write 
$$Y^\perp=\{l\in X^*\;|\; l(y)=0,\;\forall y\in Y\}$$ and in general the notation $X'$ is for the toplogical dual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint without words:

$$\forall\,l_1\,,\,l_2\in Y^\perp\;,\;\forall\,a,b\in\Bbb F\;,\;\;\text{and}\;\;\forall\,y\in Y:$$

$$(al_1+bl_2)(y):=(al_1)y+(bl_2)y:=a(l_1y)+b(l_2y)=a\cdot 0+b\cdot0=0+0=0$$